# Android - Getting data from a TextView located inside a TableRow

Tags: android, listview, onclick, textview, tablerow

Hey guys here's my problem. I have a long list of data inside a ListView (organized Alphabetically) so to make the users life easier I want to let them get directly to the part of the list they're looking for by clicking a letter (in a TextView) contained in a table (above the list).

So the user sees:

A B C D E F.... 
Item 1
Item 2
Item 3
...
...

when 'D' is clicked I'll use something like ScrollTo(position) to get to that part of the list.

How can I do this without creating 26 onClick listeners for each TextView?
My idea was to use a table and hopefully get the TextView that was clicked when the TableRow listener is activated.

OR

What would be the best way to do this?

Comment: What is the difference between creating a table, getting table row listener and creating 26 textview with click listeners? Why not you create a linearlayout and put your letters in it with click listeners?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would use a `LinearLayout` with `android:orientation="horizontal"` and put `Button`s in them for each letter. Each one have a `onClick` in your xml that calls a function. Then in the function do something like

```
int id = v.getId();
    Button btn = (Button) findViewById(id);

    String letter = btn.getText().toString();
```

Then use that letter however you had planned on searching through the list. Using `String` functions or assigning each letter to a number in the list. With something like this, you only have one `onClick` listener and use whichever `View` was clicked to search for in the list

Comment: Yup that worked great! Thanks, I didn't realize that you could call an onClick from the XML, that's really cool. Thanks for your time!

Comment: No problem. Glad I could help. Yes, calling it from XML can be real handy for certain situations